# error: Call to a member function validatePassword() on a non-object (yii2)

Tags: php, yii2

I'm new in this framework actually this is my first time to use framework. Can someone help me on this error I don't know how to fixed this error. here is my code:

User.php:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;
use Yii;
class User extends  \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $authKey;
    public $accessToken;

   public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user_file';
    }


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return isset(self::$users[$id]) ? new static(self::$users[$id]) : null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        foreach (self::$users as $user) {
            if ($user['accessToken'] === $token) {
                return new static($user);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param  string      $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        $user = User::find()
        ->where(['usr_id' => $username])
    ->all();

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param  string  $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {

        return $this->password === $password;
    }
}
```

LoginForm.php

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user = false;


    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();

            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     * @return boolean whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

Is my User.php code is correct? I really don't know the problem with my code can someone explain me what's happening?

Comment: the error is on the LoginForm in `function validatePassoword` in part of 2nd if.. im sorry if i didn't clear that one.

Comment: Use $user = $this->User();  insted of $user = $this->getUser(); in your validatePassword() method

Comment: @IshaS thank you for your response, i change my code then i tried to run it and i get this error `Calling unknown method: app\models\LoginForm::User()`

Comment: I added a answer.Create a new instance and call the function through the instance.Please look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#all()-detail all() returns an array. In findByUsername() you are returning this array. This is why you getting the call to missing member function error since an array is not an object. Try returning ->one() instead of all() like:

```
public static function findByUsername($username)
{
    $user = User::find()
    ->where(['usr_id' => $username])
->one();

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: actually i tried that and there's no error BUT i can't login, how can i see if the query is correct ? can you explain to me why my username or password is wrong? 

here is my database this are just sample :
`user_id` =  '1' | `user_password` = '1'

Comment: You could enable the yii debug toolbar (http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-debug-toolbar/), there you can see all your queries. As an alternative you could also log all statements into a file: http://www.larryullman.com/2013/09/23/debugging-database-operations-in-yii/

Answer (score 0):

Use `$user = new User();` insted of `$user = $this->getUser();` and call to method as $user->getUser() in your validatePassword() method in the LoginForm.php

Comment: i tried this code and it works, but i can't login my username or password is wrong :3 but I checked my db and it's correct, is there a possibilty that i can see what's going on on that part of logging in ?

Comment: You call to validate() function in the login method.but there is no validate() in your file.What is the method you want to call?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing -

```
$user = $this->getUser();

if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
```

Which is setting `$user` from -

```
public function getUser()
{
    if ($this->_user === false) {
        $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
    }

    return $this->_user;
}
```

Where `findByUsername()` is a method of class `Model`. In that case `$user` is not the instance of `User` class.

Try with -

```
if (!$user || !User::validatePassword($this->password)) {
```

Comment: i tried this one but it give me this: `Argument 1 passed to yii\web\User::login() must implement interface yii\web\IdentityInterface, array given, called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii2_sample1/models/LoginForm.php on line 60 and defined`