# Yii2: How can I call validatePassword() on a object?

Tags: php, yii2

I am having a similar problem to [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30390602/error-call-to-a-member-function-validatepassword-on-a-non-object-yii2#). The error I am receiving is

```
Call to a member function validatePassword() on a non-object
```

On my Users model I am using `findOne()` method to return the User object. When I try to validate user using this method on my LoginForm method I receive the error I have stated.

```
public function getUserStatus()
{
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();

        if($user || $user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
            if($user->user_status == 0) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 8;
            }
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

My getUser is the same as the one on Yii2 advanced template.

```
public function getUser()
{
    if ($this->_user === false) {
        $this->_user = Users::findByEmail($this->email, self::USER);
    }

    return $this->_user;
}
```

The problem I am facing is that when calling this there is no error:

```
if(!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password))
```

This however has an error:

```
if($user || $user->validatePassword($this->password))
```

How is this as I believe it has got to do with PHP objects itself rather than the framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check first if `$user` is not `NULL`. In your *if statements* you are facing PHP optimization (assuming `$user` is `NULL`:

```
if(!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password))
=
if (true || unknown) // first argument is satisfied and no further actions are taken (second condition is ignored)
```

---

```
if($user || $user->validatePassword($this->password))
=
if (false || unknown) // first argument is not satisfied, so PHP continues to check second parameter, thus leading to `NULL->validatePassword()`
```

Same with `if (false && someCondition)` - optimization in effect.

---

To fix that:

```
if ($user && $user->validatePassword()) { // If first argument is `false`, don't evaluate second argument. If it's `true` - validate password
```

**or**

```
if ($user) {
    if ($user->validatePassword()) {
       // valid
    } else {
       // not valid
    }
} else {
    //error
}
```

---

**YOUR EXAMPLE**

```
public function getUserStatus()
{
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();

        if($user && $user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
            return $user->user_status == 0;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: That is working but honestly I will have to go through your answer again to understand.

Comment: @Zack You are getting `NULL` as `$user` value, and than trying to access `$user->validatePassword` that translates to `NULL->validatePassword`. In your conditions you have wrong condition (`if user exists OR user password is verified` => `if user exists, forget about password and continue working`)

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks.